# Impacts of mysqldump with single-transaction argument

Tags: mysql

I found articles indicating that running "mysqldump -u user -p password --single-transaction schema > file.sql" was the right way to dump a database not locking tables, and ensuring a consistent state.

So, I was optimistic that dumping our 100GB INNODB database while our application was feeding it would have minimal impact on our application's performance. However, this turned out not to be the case. Our application's logs suggest that mysql activity was blocked for 20 minutes (the dump took about 90 minutes, so just a subset of that). Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what it was doing at that time.

Also, how does "single-transaction" work? How can it not lock tables and also capture a specific moment in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is probably more suitable for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), however...

Simply put, MySQL dump with `--single-transaction` avoids using table locks by starting a transaction with the isolation level set to `REPEATABLE READ`.

This read is a type of consistent read (i.e. other reads during the same transaction will see the original rows, even if others have changed them). Querying the same data again from within the transaction will see the original snapshot. MySQL implements this snapshot using pretty traditional [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). This is what ensures you have a consistent state when the DB is dumped (new changes are not seen by the dump transaction).

There are actually some conditions where a full table lock is still used (`--flush logs`, `--master-data`), but assuming your example command is representative, then you are not using them.

Explanation of `--single-transaction` aside, we need more info if your query is genuinely locking. If you know when your queries are being blocked then run a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` at that time to assist you in narrowing down what is happening.